# Searching for a word in inifnity loop every 10 seconds

Tags: java

Initially, the idea of ​​my program was to search for a word in a String obtained by an internet request in an infinite loop. The content downloaded from the internet (response.body ()) is updated automatically on the internet so I created an infinite loop which will receive an updated response every time it is executed. When the word "XXX" appears in the response, the program writes the time to txt file at which the word appeared in the logonTime variable (1st if), and then loops on to write down when the word disappears (2nd if). I used the Thread.Sleep () method because I got incorrect results when testing the program, and this method made them correct (I don't know why so far, maybe it's because of the contains () method and the loop was running immediately after finishing the previous iteration ).

My problem is that the program saved the result to the file 3 times correctly within a few hours, i.e. it gave the correct time of appearance and disappearance of the word, and the fourth time the time of disappearance of the word was incorrect. What could be causing this?

Output:

```
2020-12-06: 
23:25:01.685267200 - 00:32:41.391753900

2020-12-06: 
00:35:13.736545200 - 00:38:26.784442100

2020-12-06: 
00:56:44.893241100 - 00:59:26.136123800

2020-12-06: 
01:22:37.215792100 - 02:18:56.422242100 // 02:18:56.422242100 is incorrect, it was later in fact
```

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .uri(URI.create(URL))
                .build();

        boolean online = false;
        LocalTime logonTime = null;

        while (true) {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("report.txt", true));
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (!online && response.body().contains("XXX")) {
                logonTime = LocalTime.now(); // saving time when word appears in response
                online = true; // word appeared
                System.out.println("ONLINE " + LocalDate.now() + " " + LocalTime.now());
            } else if (online && !response.body().contains("XXX")) {
                bw.write(java.time.LocalDate.now() + ": \n");
                bw.write(logonTime + " - " + LocalTime.now() + "\n\n"); // writing to file when word disappeared from response
                online = false; // to allow entry back into 1st if statement
                System.out.println("OFFLINE " + LocalDate.now() + " " + LocalTime.now());
            }

            bw.close();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not checking the status of the response -- anything could have happened

Comment: @tgdavies What do you mean by this? At 02:18:56.422242100 I have entered URL I am getting response from and there was word "XXX" that I am searching for - the program claims that it was not there. How should I fix this?

Comment: @tgdavies Should I check if response.body() length is greater than 0?

Comment: You should check the `response.statusCode()`. If for some reason the request fails this could explain why the response body is not what you expected.

Comment: I have added try catch statement to print response.statusCode() when exception occurs so I will know the status code next time, but how could this be related to the fact that the program printed an incorrect disappearance time of the displayed word, i.e. 02:18:56 instead of 04:18:56 (2 hours difference). It is strange that the time differed EQUAL 2 hours. I think it may have something to do with something else, because I would get an exception earlier - my method signature: throws IOException, InterruptedException.